# Forward Wireguard traffic to another port

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-networking, port-forwarding, wireguard

I have installed Wireguard on server A with below configuration:

```
[Interface]
Address = 172.16.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <server private key>
# Firewall rules
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE


[Peer]
# Client #1 details
PublicKey = <client public key>
AllowedIPs = 172.16.0.2/32
```

And also I have opened a tcp port `(port: 6060)` on localhost of server A that if anyone connect to this port, all of it's traffic will forward to internet through server B.`(something like dynamic port forwarding)`

How can I forward all of my Wiregurad VPN clients traffic to this port `(6060)` so that if anyone connect to my VPN server, they can access internet trough server B.

My OS is: **`Ubuntu 20.04`**

Comment: This network setup is just wrong. You should avoid port-forwarding when possible, and when using VPN - this is always possible, because this is one of the goals of VPN - to get you the clear and simple internal network connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, I guess you are trying to forward to port to your WireGuard client?

```
# Allow communication between WireGuard peers and MASQUERADE traffic
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE;
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE;

# Port forwarding for single port to 172.16.0.2
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.0.2; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 172.16.0.2 --dport 6000 -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.0.1;
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.0.2; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 172.16.0.2 --dport 6000 -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.0.1;
```

That should let you forward port to your client IP.